# hide drop down based on if value is in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following script to check if a postcode is an an array, if so it will hide a drop down:

```
var postcodes = ["AL1 1", "AL1 2", "AL1 3", "AL1 4", "AL1 5", "AL1 9"];
if (ukpostcode in postcodes) {
    id_test_question.setVisible(false);
}
```

This doesn't work, any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, you cannot do the `if-statement` you have.

Instead, try something like this:

```
var postcodes = ["AL1 1", "AL1 2", "AL1 3", "AL1 4", "AL1 5", "AL1 9"];
if (postcodes.indexOf(ukpostcode) !== -1) {
    id_test_question.setVisible(false);
}
```

From your question, I cannot tell if the line `id_test_question.setVisible(false);` works, but this way the if statement will check if `ukpostcode` is at any index within `postcodes`. If there is no value `ukpostcode` inside `postcodes`, `.indexOf()` will return -1, and therefore `.setVisible(false)` will not run.

Hopefully this helps!